# Solve a matrix equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I need to find $X$ from

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\\ 
-3 &-6 
\end{pmatrix} X \begin{pmatrix}
1 &2 \\ 
-1 &-2 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
2 &4 \\ 
-6 & -12
\end{pmatrix}$$

I wrote $X$ as

$$X=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\ 
c &d 
\end{pmatrix}$$

and I got $a+2c-b-2d=2$ but I do not know what to do next. Please help.

Comment: Hint: look up inverses of matrices and then try using $A^{-1} A = I$ and apply it to something like: $AB = C$ implies $ B = A^{-1} C$

Comment: @TheMathsGeek Every single matrix here has determinant $0$.

Comment: Determinant is 0 so there is no inverse

Comment: Right you are! I'm blaming the lack of coffee this morning...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are on good way. When you multiply matrices on left side, you finally get $$a-b+2c-2d = 2$$ which is a linear equation. Solutions are given with three parameters, and thus

$$ X = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & \frac{a-b+2c-2}{2}
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: So you let it like that?

Comment: Yes, you have shown that your matrix equation is equivalent to linear equation $a-b+2c-2d=2$ yourself. Thus, solutions for your matrix equation are $3$-dimensional (+ particular solution).